# Format of $fieldList in Model::saveAll()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

[According to the CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array), you can pass a $fieldList option to Model::saveAll to restrict saving to only certain fields.  However, it completely neglects to give an example of the correct format of the parameter.  What's the appropriate format of a $fieldList in the context of saveAll(), specifically saveAssociated(), when you want to enumerate fields on multiple related models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is actually for the `save()` method. The `saveAll()` method only [takes two parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html?#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array).

The second parameter of `saveAll()` is an array of options, of which one can be `fieldList`. This is equivalent to the `fieldList` parameter of the `save()` method.

It states this parameter is an array of field names.

```
$this->Model->saveAll($data, array(
  'fieldList' => array(
    'id', 'title', 'etc', 'etc'
  )
));
```

Comment: Corrected, although that'd be limited to one model. Perhaps it's something like `Model.field`. I need to tinker with it a bit I guess.

Comment: The format for multiple models is: `array('SomeModel' => array('field'),'AssociatedModel' => array('field', 'otherfield'))`